# How to use Amplify Auth AccessToken in Okhttp3 Interceptor

Tags: android, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using Amplify SDK auth in my Android project to get the user access-token, and pass access token in api calls as request header. my current implementation is this and it's working,

```
   override suspend fun getUserProfile(): UserProfile {
    val session = Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()
    val token = (session as AWSCognitoAuthSession).userPoolTokens.value?.accessToken
        ?: throw UnauthorisedAccessException()
    val currentUser = Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser() ?: throw UnauthorisedAccessException()

    return apiService.getUserProfile(
        accessToken = token,
        userId = currentUser.userId
    ).mapToDomain()
}
```

I  want to use Okhttp Interceptor to provide this access tokens to API calls, this my current implementation,

class AmplifyAuthorizationHeaderInterceptor : Interceptor {

```
private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)


@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    var request = chain.request()

    // Get the access token from the authenticator.
    val token = coroutineScope.async {
            val session = Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()
            (session as AWSCognitoAuthSession).userPoolTokens.value?.accessToken
    }
    token.invokeOnCompletion {
        request =   if (it == null) {
           request.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", token.getCompleted()!!)
                .build()
        }else{
            request
        }
    }
    return chain.proceed(request)
}
```

}

but this is not working, not sure what's the issue, always returning 401 for api calls.

Answer (score 0):

I use to do it like this. It retrieves the token directly from `AWSMobileClient`.

```kotlin
class AmplifyAuthorizationHeaderInterceptor : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var request = chain.request()

        // Get the access token from the authenticator.
        val token = AWSMobileClient.getInstance().tokens.idToken.tokenString
        request = req.newBuilder().addHeader(
            name = "Authorization",
            value = token
        ).build()

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

Bear in mind that if it's still returning the unauthorize error, the issue may not be in the client but with some config in Cognito.

Comment: thanks for sharing this code, unfortunately I'm still getting the 401, I can see  Authorization getting pass now, looks like it's not the correct token to access the APIs, but this line works for me                                                                                          >>> val token =  AWSMobileClient.getInstance().tokens.accessToken.tokenString